# Managing CSS flex-box growth in multi-line to create a grid of equal blocks

Tags: css, flexbox

I am looking for a way to create **equally sized** boxes with `flexbox` while using `flex-growth: 1`. This works pretty good by defining the parent with:

```
display: flex;
flex-flow: row-wrap;
```

and its children with:

```
flex: 1 0 10rem;
```

However, the LAST line will (depending on the amount of blocks in that line) have different widths for its boxes in comparison to the boxes in the previous lines. Is there a way to work around this while still using flex-grow?

#### HTML

```
<section>
    <div>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
    <div>bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</div>
    <div>cccccccccccccccccccc</div>
    <div>dddddddddddddddddddd</div>
    <div>eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee</div>
    <div>ffffffffffffffffffff</div>
    <div>gggggggggggggggggggg</div>
</section>
```

#### CSS

```
section {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 700px;
}

div {
    background-color: red;
    height: 100px;
    flex: 1 0 200px;
}

div:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Note in http://jsfiddle.net/C2q8D/3/ that the flex items in the last line are bigger than the lines above (as there are less items on that line to divide the space).

Comment: I have a similar problem as illustrated by this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d9a9282v/ . Basically I'm making a gallery thing that I want to be a bit elastic but still change between one or two items per row depending on what fits.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is totally possible, however, you have to know how many columns you'll have at a maximum. http://jsfiddle.net/kelunik/C2q8D/6/

### Solution

By adding a few empty placeholders, your cards get equally sized. You just have to make sure, you're adding enough placeholders. It doesn't matter if there are too many, because they'll have a height of zero and are not visible.

#### CSS

```
section {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    background-color: blue;
}

div {
    background-color: red;
    height: 3rem;
    flex: 1 0 10rem;
}

div:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: green;
}

div:empty {
    margin: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 0;
    background: transparent;
}
```

#### HTML

```
<section>
    <div>a</div>
    <div>b</div>
    <div>c</div>
    <div>d</div>
    <div>e</div>
    <div>f</div>
    <div>g</div>
    <div>h</div>
    <div>i</div>
    <div>j</div>
    <div>k</div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</section>
```

Comment: But in this case, we don't know how many columns we'll have.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like if flex-grow is set to 1, you have explicitly declared that you don't care for the boxes to be equally sized — when a given line has fewer items, you have instructed it to grow larger than your flex-basis.

Does setting a `max-width` on items equal to your `flex-basis` achieve what you want?  See http://jsfiddle.net/C2q8D/4/ for that. I added a `justify-content` property to the flex container as well; just experimenting myself with how it affects this layout.