# How can I allow flex-items to grow while keeping the same size?

Tags: css, flexbox

Flexbox is one of the coolest tools a web designer could wish for. Unfortunately, sometimes it's not immediately obvious what I'm supposed to do. Take, for example, [this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/56KRUZdVszZLWTkbqYJN?p=preview). I'd like for the items to expand to fill the row, without expanding all the way across in the last row.
My CSS contains this important stuff:

```
.recipe-picker recipe {
    -webkit-flex: 0 1 8em;
    flex: 0 1 8em;
    
    height: 12em;
}
```

If I change the `0` to any positive number (which corresponds to the `flex-grow` property), the last item row will stretch in a super ugly way. The rest of the items behave rather nicely, but the last row should keep the same size as the rest of the items.
What can I do to fix this behavior?

Comment: wouldn't it be flex-grow? Try flex-grow: 1;

Comment: the 0 corresponds to the flex-grow property, so adding that line would cause the behavior I mentioned above. I edited my question to clarify

Comment: I don't think you can do this using flexbox. But maybe you can with [grid layout](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-grid/).

Comment: @Oriol using CSS Grids would be nice, but HTML5Please says I [should avoid using them](http://html5please.com/#grid)

Comment: It’s not perfect, but this is the only solution I’ve seen that achieves the desired effect using Flexbox: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28616083/1922441

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to keep wrapped flex-items the same width as the elements on the previous row?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23274338/how-to-keep-wrapped-flex-items-the-same-width-as-the-elements-on-the-previous-ro)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is something that cannot be expressed via CSS Flexbox right now. Someone [asked basically this exact question](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2015Jan/0136.html) on the CSS Working Group Mailing List a few days ago, and the [response](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2015Jan/0150.html) was: "At the moment, no, this is not possible.  This is a high-priority item for Flexbox 2, though.

You may be able to hack up something like you want using `max-width`, though -- that'll prevent flex items (particularly those on the last line) from growing indefinitely. Here's a [forked version of your plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/HPj9NJfCTFYuMT81UFhj?p=preview) with a nonzero flex-grow, and with `max-width: 10em`.

(I chose `10em` arbitrarily; you could also use e.g. `max-width: calc(100%/5)`, if you want to make sure each flex item takes up no more than 1/5 of the line, for example.)

Comment: I only hope that we'll be able to update this question sooner rather than later for Flexbox 2.

Answer (score 1):

I achieved what you were looking for by adjusting `flex-shrink`.

```
.recipe-picker recipe {
flex: 0 0 8em;
}
```

I try to think of `flex-grow` and `flex-shrink` as "permission to expand". When either has a value, that means the element has permission to grow. When all elements have flex-grow, they will expand to the same size. But, the same rule holds true if they all have a `flex-shrink` value, too.

http://plnkr.co/edit/sxHUzIRPlbstpOzoGcR6?p=preview

Comment: Unfortunately, what you posted doesn't allow the items to expand to fill the box while keeping the same size, they just stay at one static size.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, and managed to find a fully working *workaround* to deal with this flexbox shortcoming.

Given that this is a duplicate of [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23274338/how-to-keep-wrapped-flex-items-the-same-width-as-the-elements-on-the-previous-ro), and it would be wrong to copy my answer here again, I'm going to link to it, for those Googlers who find themselves here and not there:

[How to keep wrapped flex-items the same width as the elements on the previous row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23274338/how-to-keep-wrapped-flex-items-the-same-width-as-the-elements-on-the-previous-ro)