# Group of items with responsive equal width in multi-line context, issue with last-line

Tags: css, alignment, flexbox, multiline, responsive

After researching the question for a while and considering all the `float` and `text-align` alternatives, I'm mostly happy with the solution that I've found using flexbox but there is an issue with the last line (when it overflows) in that the items are not the same width as those in the previous lines because they are allowed to stretch more (up to max-width) in order to try to fill the remaining empty space.

My requirements are simple:
1. All items must have the same width (including on the last line);
2. All items must be equallys spaced if the line is full or aligned left if not (typically last line);
3. Items can (must) overflow when min-width is reached (responsive resizing);
4. CSS-only solution and possibly avoiding media queries;
5. I'd rather use `flex-basis: 0` for true same width (last line issue standing);
6. Non-flexbox solution considered as long as meet other requirements;

I've removed vendor prefixes for clarity but I'm using them on the actual page.

**CSS**

```
nav {
  margin:           20px 0px;
}
nav #linkgroup {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;   /* aligns left when not full */
  align-items: center;
  align-content: space-around;
}
nav #linkgroup .link {
  min-width: 120px;
  width: 120px;   /* only used because of Safari issue below */
  max-width: 160px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 5px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: auto;   /* 0 gives all exact same size but have to use auto and set 'width' for Safari issue https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=136041 */
  line-height: 30px;   /* set equal to height, for vertical align trick */
  text-align: center;
}
nav #linkgroup .link a.btn {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: normal;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  border: solid #1f628d 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

**HTML**

```
  <nav>
    <div id="linkgroup">
      <div class="link"><a class="btn" href="#">A</a></div>
      <div class="link"><a class="btn" href="#">AB</a></div>
      <div class="link"><a class="btn" href="#">ABC</a></div>
      <div class="link"><a class="btn" href="#">ABCD</a></div>
      <div class="link"><a class="btn" href="#">ABCDE</a></div>
      <div class="link"><a class="btn" href="#">ABCDEF</a></div>
      <div class="link"><a class="btn" href="#">ABCDEFG</a></div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

```css
nav {
  margin:           20px 0px;
  padding:          0px 0px 5px 0px;   /* to space when multi-line */
}
nav #linkgroup {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;   /* aligns left when not full */
  align-items: center;
  align-content: space-around;
}
nav #linkgroup .link {
  min-width: 120px;
  width: 120px;   /* only used because of Safari issue below */
  max-width: 160px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 5px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: auto;   /* 0 gives all exact same size but have to use auto and set 'width' for Safari issue https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=136041 */
  line-height: 30px;   /* set equal to height, for vertical align trick */
  text-align: center;
}
nav #linkgroup .link a.btn {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: normal;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  border: solid #1f628d 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <div id="linkgroup">
      <div class="link"><a class="btn" href="#">A</a></div>
      <div class="link"><a class="btn" href="#">AB</a></div>
      <div class="link"><a class="btn" href="#">ABC</a></div>
      <div class="link"><a class="btn" href="#">ABCD</a></div>
      <div class="link"><a class="btn" href="#">ABCDE</a></div>
      <div class="link"><a class="btn" href="#">ABCDEF</a></div>
      <div class="link"><a class="btn" href="#">ABCDEFG</a></div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: Apologies for this, it's the second time that I find an answer in the sidebar - after posting the question - because the suggested ones when composing the question are not "precise" enough while the algorithm to show related ones in the sidebar is apparently much better.
The answer is basically [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28616083/6040668) but I improved on it by keeping `margin` and `border` the same and using a single media query to `display: none;` the "empty" items if the page is wide enough to have all items on the first line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:
Simply add as many "empty" items as you expect the maximum on a line to be (a few more don't hurt but have at least enough for a full line) and then add the two bits relating to `div:empty` from the CSS below.

**CSS**

```
nav {
  margin:           20px 0px;
}
nav #linkgroup {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;   /* aligns left when not full */
  align-items: center;
  align-content: space-around;
}
nav #linkgroup .link {
  min-width: 120px;
  width: 120px;   /* only used because of Safari issue below */
  max-width: 160px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 5px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: auto;   /* 0 gives all exact same size but have to use auto and set 'width' for Safari issue https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=136041 */
  line-height: 30px;   /* set equal to height, for vertical align trick */
  text-align: center;
}
nav #linkgroup .link a.btn {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: normal;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  border: solid #1f628d 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#linkgroup > div:empty {
    height: 0;   /* I think visibility: hidden; would do the same */
}
@media only screen
 and (min-width: 1030px) {
  #linkgroup > div:empty {
      display: none;
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
  <nav>
    <div id="linkgroup">
      <div class="link"><a class="btn" href="#">A</a></div>
      <div class="link"><a class="btn" href="#">AB</a></div>
      <div class="link"><a class="btn" href="#">ABC</a></div>
      <div class="link"><a class="btn" href="#">ABCD</a></div>
      <div class="link"><a class="btn" href="#">ABCDE</a></div>
      <div class="link"><a class="btn" href="#">ABCDEF</a></div>
      <div class="link"><a class="btn" href="#">ABCDEFG</a></div>
      <div class="link"></div>
      <div class="link"></div>
      <div class="link"></div>
      <div class="link"></div>
      <div class="link"></div>
      <div class="link"></div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set flex-grow property to 0 in nav #linkgroup .link:

```
flex-grow: 0;
```

It will avoid the unwanted growing of divs on the last line.